# PHP: Detect and show "Server overloaded" message

Tags: php, apache, optimization, lamp

I have noticed a few websites such as [hypem.com](http://hypem.com/) show a "You didnt get served" error message when the site is busy rather than just letting people wait, time out or refresh; aggravating what is probably a server load issue.

> We are too loaded to process your request. Please click "back" in your
>   browser and try what you were doing again.

How is this achieved before the server becomes overloaded? It sounds like a really neat way to manage user expectation if a site happens to get overloaded whilst also giving the site time to recover.

Answer (score 3):

Another options is this:

```
$load = sys_getloadavg();
if ($load[0] > 80) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Too busy, try again later');
    die('Server too busy. Please try again later.');
}
```

I got it from php's site http://php.net/sys_getloadavg, altough I'm not sure what the values represent that the sys_getloadavg returns

Answer (score 2):

You could simply create a 500.html file and have your webserver use that whenever a 50x error is thrown.

I.e. in your apache config:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
```

Or use a [php shutdown function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to check if the request timeout (which defaults to 30s) has been reached and if so - redirect/render something static (so that rendering the error itself cannot cause problems).

Note that most sites where you'll see a "This site is taking too long to respond" message are effectively generating that message with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php tick function to detect when a server isn't loading for a specified amount of time, then display an error messages. Basic usage:

```
<?php 
$connection  = false; 
function checkConnection( $connectionWaitingTime = 3 ) 
{ 
    // check connection & time 
    global $time,$connection; 
    if( ($t = (time() - $time)) >= $connectionWaitingTime && !$connection){  
        echo ("<p> Server not responding  for <strong>$t</strong> seconds !! </p>"); 
        die("Connection aborted");             
    } 
} 

register_tick_function("checkConnection"); 
$time = time(); 
declare (ticks=1) 
{ 
   require 'yourapp.php' // load your main app logic
    $connection = true ; 
}
```

The while(true) is just to simulate a loaded server.
To implement the script in your site, you need to remove the while statement and add your page logic E.G dispatch event or front controller action etc.

And the $connectionWaitingTime in the checkCOnnection function is set to timeout after 3 seconds, but you can change that to whatever you want

Comment: a tick function? seriously? you want to _add load_ to detect when the server is loaded?

Comment: Could explain a little more what is happening here? What is `register_tick_function` doing and will it actually the site down itself?

Comment: A tick is an event that occurs for every N low-level tickable statements executed by the parser within the declare block. The value for N is specified using ticks=N within the declare blocks's directive section.

register_tick_function — Register a function for execution on each tick.

So if anything on the server takes longer than 3 seconds to execute, then it can display your error message.

@AD7six the register_shutdown_function is worse then the tick function, as the user will then have to wait for the default 30 seconds timeout before an error page is shown

Comment: @AD7six also a 500 server error won't work, as sometimes the server just takes long to respond, and never returns with a 500 server error.

Comment: @pierre don't "optimize" code such that it's designed for a worse case scenario - design for the happy path but fail gracefully. I disagree with your definition of worse. General loss of connectivity has to be handled with js (as suggested by @julien_c) if at all.

Comment: @AD7six the register_shutdown_function registers a callback to be executed after script execution finishes or exit() is called. So to use it to test for lost of connectivity won't help, as it won't even execute if the server is overloaded. I agree with 'design for the happy path but fail gracefully', but sometimes it is better to code for a worst case scenario

Comment: @AD7six in my answer I have said "The while(true) is just to simulate a loaded server. To implement the script in your site, you need to remove the while statement and add your page logic E.G dispatch event or front controller action etc." IE. it's just a test script to show how it will work. Your actual page logic will be in the place of the while statement

Comment: I agree it could have been a bit misleading, I have changed it as per your suggestion

Comment: @Pierre i know this question is old, but would server overload be either error 500 or error 408? If it would be one of those, i could just use .htaccess to do this. Thanks!

Comment: @pattyd You can set your own status code. If you don't set any headers, it will automatically respond with 200. How would you accomplish this in htaccess?

Comment: @Pierre I would tell it to redirect errors 500 and 408 to a custom page. So i should tell it to redirect error 200 too?

Answer (score 1):

This may be to do with the database connection timing out, but that assumes that your server has a bigger DB load than CPU load when times get tough. If this is the case, you can make your DB connector show the message if no connection happens for 1 second.

You could also use a quick query to the logs table to find out how many hits/second there are and automatically not respond to any more after a certain point in order to preserve QOS for the others. In this case, you would have to set that level manually, based on server logs. An alternative method can be seen [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!throttle!throttle.module/function/throttle_exit/5) in the Drupal throttle module.

Another alternative would be to use the Apache status page to get information on how many child processes are free and to throttle id there are none left as per @giltotherescue's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67819/how-to-get-the-number-of-apache-children-free-within-php).

Comment: Sounds interesting Matt - how do I detect if it hasnt connected to the DB in N seconds?

Comment: ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 5); Then check whether the connector is false or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the maximum connection in apache configuration too...

Refer

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients

http://www.howtoforge.com/configuring_apache_for_maximum_performance

Answer (score 1):

This is not a strictly PHP solution, but you could do like Twitter, i.e.:

- serve a **mostly static HTML and Javascript** app from a CDN or another server of yours
- the calls to the actual heavy work server-side (PHP in your case) functions/APIs are actually done **in AJAX** from one of your static JS files
- so you can set a **timeout on your AJAX calls** and return a "Seems like loading tweets may take longer than expected"-like notice.

Comment: I think converting to a SPA is probably out of scope - but a good suggestion nonetheless.