# Is there a way to set the .htaccess to display a page if the server is busy?

Tags: .htaccess

I use a free web-host and since the server is not top class, often an error comes up saying the server is busy. I am scared that this might send the user off to somewhere else.

I would like to know if I can edit the .htaccess to send the user to a webpage explaining the server is busy. If this is not possible to do, please tell me the alternative options. I have searched online but to no avail.

Comment: see if your host allows you to create custom 404 pages and apply to same to redirect 500 errors.

Comment: I think that's error 503, service not available, try using `ErrorDocument 503 /503.html` and see if that works or 500 [or you can try these.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716976/php-detect-and-show-server-overloaded-message)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try both 500 and 503.